# How to add new line break to a cell formula in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have MS Excel looks like this.

```
A            B          C
---------------------------------
Name         Age        Gender
---------------------------------
Tom Hanks    67         Male
---------------------------------
Jennifer Ann 58         Female
---------------------------------
Mark T       53         Male
```

I want to create a formula in column D

that gives me the result in this format.

```
D
---------------------------------
Info
---------------------------------
Tom Hanks
67
Male
---------------------------------
Jennifer Ann
58
Female
---------------------------------
Mark T
53
Male
```

I tried this formula but did not work

```
=A2 & "\n\r" & B2  & "\n\r" & C2
```

but what I got was

```
Tom Hanks\n\r67\n\rMale
```

how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use any one of the following depending on your excel version:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>D2</kbd> --> works with Excel 2019+ onwards.

```
=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),,A2:C2)
```

---

Or,

• Formula used in cell <kbd>E2</kbd> --> believe it works across all versions

```
=A2&CHAR(10)&B2&CHAR(10)&C2
```

---

Or,

• Formula used in cell <kbd>F2</kbd> --> Works with `MS365` only

```
=MAP(A2:A4,B2:B4,C2:C4,LAMBDA(x,y,z,TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),,x,y,z)))
```

---

Note: In all the above formulas you need to hit the wrap feature available under Home Ribbon in Alignment Group.

---

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding "\n\r", you could use another character as delimiter, then format the target cells by replacing that character with "CTRL+J".

Not sure if you could simply add CTRL+J as a special string character though.

Edit: seems like on Windows, you could use `cell1 & CHAR(10) & cell2 & CHAR(10) & cell3`

And as Mayukh Bhattacharya suggested, the textjoin version which is more concise:

```
TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10), TRUE, cell1, cell2, cell3, …)
```

Comment: they concat as Char(10) does not exist , not new line

Comment: Did you turn on "Wrap text" option?